# JacksonMapper Date deserialization with UTC time zone fails with given format

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml, date

I know there are many duplicate questions about the same issue, however, I wasn't able to deserialize given date format into `java.util.Date` object. The client api I am using returns date fields with 6 digit combined with milliseconds and nanoseconds.

- 2016-12-08T20:09:05.508883Z
- 2016-12-08T20:09:05.527Z

Sometimes it includes nano seconds sometimes not. I tried to follow deserialization examples from [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/jdk/DateDeserializationTZTest.java) library itself however couldn't found a workaround. Say this is the example json blob

```
{
    "id": "68e6a28f-ae28-4788-8d4f-5ab4e5e5ae08",
    "created_at": "2016-12-08T20:09:05.508883Z",
    "done_at": "2016-12-08T20:09:05.527Z"
}
```

**Entity.java**

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OrderResponse {
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'*'", timezone = "UTC")
    private Date createdAt;

    @JsonProperty("done_at")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'*'", timezone = "UTC")
    private Date doneAt;
}
```

If I only use format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` jackson mapper deserializes with timezone coming from jvm itself. But I need to use UTC format and I tried also implementing custom deserializer and serializer which doesn't work as well. My question is `java.util.Date` correct object type? Additionally, I also tried to create my own object mapper with registering `new JavaTimeModule()` but it didn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: ...Your problem mostly stems from the fact that you're using `java.util.Date`, which should be put out of its misery.  Are you able to switch to a more appropriate type, like `java.time.Instant` (although this will require loading an additional jackson module for best support)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yeah I can move from Date to Instant however I wasn't able to parse given format to Instant as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` has `ISO_INSTANT` format type which supports the format I was looking for.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT

Basically, I wrote my custom deserializer

```
public class CustomInstantDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return Instant.from(fmt.parse(p.getText()));
    }
}
```

with `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on related field.

```
@JsonProperty("created_at")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomInstantDeserializer.class)
private Instant createdAt;
```